# Is there any pytorch function can combine the specific continuous dimensions of tensor into one?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

Let's call the function I'm looking for "`magic_combine`", which can combine the continuous dimensions of tensor I give to it. For more specific, I want it to do the following thing:

```
a = torch.zeros(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)  
b = a.magic_combine(2, 5) # combine dimension 2, 3, 4 
print(b.size()) # should be (1, 2, 60, 6)
```

I know that `torch.view()` can do the similar thing. But I'm just wondering if there is any more elegant way to achieve the goal?

Comment: What kind of shape would you expect if the provided indices aren't continuous? E.g. should `a.magic_combine(0, 2, 4)` be of shape `(15, 2, 4, 6)`, `(2, 15, 4, 6)`, or  `(2, 4, 15, 6)`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I‘m now focusing on continuous situation and I did not express it perfectly with my original question. I have corrected it now.

Comment: I don't think there exists one, though it should be easy to implement using `.view
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what you have in mind with "a more elegant way", but [`Tensor.view()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.view) has the advantage not to re-allocate data for the view (original tensor and view share the same data), making this operation quite light-weight.

As mentioned by @UmangGupta, it is however rather straight-forward to wrap this function to achieve what you want, e.g.:

```python
import torch

def magic_combine(x, dim_begin, dim_end):
    combined_shape = list(x.shape[:dim_begin]) + [-1] + list(x.shape[dim_end:])
    return x.view(combined_shape)

a = torch.zeros(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
b = magic_combine(a, 2, 5) # combine dimension 2, 3, 4
print(b.size())
# torch.Size([1, 2, 60, 6])
```

Answer (score 18):

```
a = torch.zeros(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
b = a.view(*a.shape[:2], -1, *a.shape[5:])
```

Seems to me a bit simpler than the [current accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51002923/913098) and doesn't go through a `list` constructor (3 times).

Answer (score 16):

There is a variant of `flatten` that takes `start_dim` and `end_dim` parameters.  You can call it in the same way as your `magic_combine` (except that `end_dim` is inclusive).

```py
a = torch.zeros(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)  
b = a.flatten(2, 4) # combine dimension 2, 3, 4 
print(b.size()) # should be (1, 2, 60, 6)
```

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.flatten.html

There is also a corresponding `unflatten`, in which you can specify a dimension to unflatten and a shape to unflatten it to.

Answer (score 4):

Also possible with [torch einops](http://einops.rocks/pytorch-examples.html).

[Github](https://pythonrepo.com/repo/arogozhnikov-einops-python-deep-learning).

```
> pip install einops
```

```
from einops import rearrange

a = torch.zeros(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
b = rearrange(a, 'd0 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 -> d0 d1 (d2 d3 d4) d5')
```